# "executor": "@nx/vite:test" doesn't create coverage when running from `nx affected`

Tags: vitest, yarn-workspaces, nomachine-nx

We have a monorepo with `yarn workspaces` that uses nx to manage targets (=package.json scripts) and it runs `jest` by default for `test` target (defined with jest plugin in `targetDefaults`)

However, in 1 project we use `vitest` and I've changed the target to use `@nx/vite:test` with relevant configuration:

```json
"test": {
      "executor": "@nx/vite:test",
      "outputs": ["{projectRoot}/coverage"],
      "options": {
        "configFile": "{projectRoot}/vite.config.ts",
        "reportsDirectory": "{projectRoot}/coverage"
      },
      "cache": true
    },
```

All of this is exactly according to the nx documentation[https://nx.dev/nx-api/vite/executors/test].

When running the target (`test`) in the project directory, it works and creates the coverage folder as output, but when running from root folder with `nx affected --target-test` it doesn't produce the coverage directory although it hits the correct target.

I've verified the specific project nx configuration using `yarn nx show project myVitestProj`.

Did anyone encounter this? Couldn't find any hint in Github issues and nx Discord.

Comment: Opened an [issue in nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/22166), since this is probably a bug.